# Android BLE : Weight data from the BLE Scale - Need to convert byte array to decimal weight value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I connected my app with a BLE weight scale device and I'm able to get the byte array from the device.but I couldn't able to convert the byte array to my weight.
the weight value is coming in the 6th position of the byte array. I have some test cases as follows.

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, **32**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] =========32gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, **1, 108**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ========364gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, **-17**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ========239gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] =======364gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ========325gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]==========333gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 2, 91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] =========603gm

[-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 4, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] =========1040gm

It seems like 5th and 6th values are dependent.Please help me on converting this to weight value.

Comment: Do you mind telling the BLE scale that you are using? I'll start working in a project to develop a Flutter app to get the weight from a B LE weight scale but I dont have any idea where to start. thanks

Comment: @RodRodrigues its Sensodroid S5000

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to receive is a Short value stored in two bytes at position 5 and 6. The easiest way to decode bytes to primitive in kotlin jvm is to wrap this part of the data into a ByteBuffer and decode it.

From one of your line

> [-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ========364gm

```kotlin
val bleByteArray = byteArrayOf(-6, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bleByteArray, 5, Short.SIZE_BYTES)
assert(buffer.getShort() == 364)
```

Here, `buffer` only contains bytes 5 and 6. So when `getShort` is called, the buffer read the first two bytes and return the corresponding short value.

If you want to read other parts of the ble information, you may want to `wrap()` the whole ByteArray and then read multiple parts of it with other methods of [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Comment: have found another method also. 
**fun toPositiveInt(base:Byte,weight:Byte) = base.toUByte().toInt() shl 8 or weight.toUByte().toInt()** // base is 1 and weight is 108 from the bytearray.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the incoming data is typed as byte[32] and saved into an array named ble:

int weight = (ble[5] << 8) | ble[6];

Remember that Java arrays start with index 0, so the first element is ble[0], not ble[1]. That's why the above code uses array elements 5 and 6 - they are actually the 6th and 7th elements of the array.